# Using afterDelete trigger to modify a lot of users

Tags: parse-platform, triggers, parse-cloud-code

When a specific object is deleted, I need to use an `afterDelete` trigger to remove references to the object that was just deleted. Specifically, the User class has a column that is a pointer to an object of the type that was just deleted. Therefore I need to unset that column for users who had that set to the object that was just deleted. To do this I am querying for the users, looping over the results of the query, `unset`ing the attribute, then calling `saveAll`. My worry is that the results of the query may return a lot of users, and I need to ensure all of them are updated.

My question is, do Cloud Code triggers have the 1000 max query limit? Is there a better way to unset this pointer once that object is deleted? Is there no automatic removal of pointers to this deleted object?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Book", function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var book = request.object;

    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo("Favorite_Book", book);
    userQuery.limit(1000);
    userQuery.find( {
        success:function(users){
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                users[i].unset("Favorite_Book");
            }
            Parse.Object.saveAll(users, {
                success: function(users) {},
                error: function(users, error) {
                    console.error("Failed to update users: " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
                }
            });
        }, error: function(error) {
            console.error("Failed to fetch users: " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two issue you need to know:

1. Parse query returns only maximum of 1000 records. To process more records, you need paginate the results using `skip` method on your query object. You can use [Promises in Series](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-promises-in-series) to process all your records in batches of 1000 records.
2. On Parse free plan, you are limited to make only 1800 requests per minute. This means that you cannot save/update a large number of records over a short time span.